# Edit hashmap in JSF or Primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have an object that represents a service provider. In that object I have this hashmap

```
private Map<MetaDataKeys, String> metaData;
```

The "MetaDatatKeys" is a enum that looks like this,

```
public enum MetaDataKeys {
    PROVIDER_NAME, PROVIDER_CONTACT_NAME, PROVIDER_SERVICE_RADIUS;
}
```

I would like to display the hashmap key/value pairs in a datatable or similar for editing, something along the lines of,

```
            <p:dataTable id="providerDatatable" var="infoMap" value="#{editUserBean.editUser.metaData}">
                <p:column><h:outputText value="#{infoMap.key.metaData}"/></p:column>
                <p:column><h:inputText value="#{infoMap.key.value}"/></p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

In my backing bean "editUser" is the object that contains the map.

what is the best way to go about this? I have not been successful in even getting the table to render and populate with values. In searching most examples use a string or a primitive for the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make iteration in the datatable by `Map.entrySet()` it's better way. If you try to do itaration by `Map.keySet()` and than take value by key you can take O(n^2).

For your task realisation looks like:

```
<p:dataTable id="providerDatatable" var="infoMap" value="#{editUserBean.editUser.metaData.entrySet()}">
    <p:column><h:outputText value="#{infoMap.key}"/></p:column>
    <p:column><h:inputText value="#{infoMap.value}"/></p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

To edit table row you can you use `p:cellEditor` more info about this component you can find at the [Primefaces show case](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml)